# Sequelize - scope with include

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize in my Node.js/Express app with the notion of scopes (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/scopes/).

I would like to have two scopes on a Model. Each of these scope are based on a join of another table (see the two scopes `inLocation` & `withExpertises`):

```
const Agency = sequelize.define("agency", {
    id:            { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true },
    name:          DataTypes.STRING,
    address:       DataTypes.STRING,
    size:          DataTypes.INTEGER,
    description:   DataTypes.TEXT,
    logoFileName:  { type: DataTypes.STRING, field: "logo_file_name" },
    externalScore: { type: DataTypes.FLOAT, field: "external_score" }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate(models) {
        Agency.belongsToMany(models.location, {
          through:    "locationsAgency",
          foreignKey: "location_id"
        });
        Agency.hasOne(models.locationsAgency);
        Agency.hasMany(models.service);
      }
    },
    scopes: {
      inLocation(locationId) {
        return {
          include: [{
            model: locationsAgency, where: { locationId: locationId }
          }]
        };
      },
      withExpertises(expertiseIds) {
        return {
          include: [{
            model: service, where: { expertiseId: expertiseIds }
          }]
        };
      },
      orderByRelevance: {
        order: '"externalScore" DESC'
      }
    }
  });
```

When I'm doing the following call:

```
models.agency.scope({ method: ["inLocation", 9260] },
                    { method: ["withExpertises", 79] },
                    "orderByRelevance")
             .findAll({ limit: 10 })
```

I have this SQL generated:

```
SELECT "agency".*, 
"services"."id" AS "services.id", 
"services"."expertise_id" AS "services.expertiseId"
FROM (
    SELECT "agency".*, 
    "locationsAgency"."id" AS "locationsAgency.id",
    "locationsAgency"."location_id" AS "locationsAgency.locationId",
    "locationsAgency"."agency_id" AS "locationsAgency.agencyId" 
    FROM "agencies" AS "agency" 
    INNER JOIN "locations_agencies" AS "locationsAgency" ON "agency"."id" = "locationsAgency"."agency_id" 
    AND "locationsAgency"."location_id" = 9260 
    WHERE ( 
        SELECT "agency_id" 
        FROM "services" AS "service" 
        WHERE ("service"."agency_id" = "agency"."id" AND "service"."expertise_id" = 79) 
        LIMIT 1 
    ) 
    IS NOT NULL LIMIT 10
) AS "agency" 
INNER JOIN "services" AS "services" ON "agency"."id" = "services"."agency_id" 
AND "services"."expertise_id" = 79 
ORDER BY "externalScore" DESC
```

As you can see, the scope are nested in the FROM-clause, which give me a awful SQL and then the `limit` statement is not a the good place.

I expected to have this following SQL query:

```
SELECT "agency".*, 
"services"."id" AS "services.id", 
"services"."expertise_id" AS "services.expertiseId", 
"services"."created_at" AS "services.created_at", 
"services"."updated_at" AS "services.updated_at",
"locationsAgency"."id" AS "locationsAgency.id", 
"locationsAgency"."location_id" AS "locationsAgency.locationId", 
"locationsAgency"."agency_id" AS "locationsAgency.agencyId"
FROM "agencies" AS "agency"
INNER JOIN "locations_agencies" AS "locationsAgency" ON "agency"."id" = "locationsAgency"."agency_id" 
INNER JOIN "services" AS "services" ON "agency"."id" = "services"."agency_id" 
AND "locationsAgency"."location_id" = 9260 
AND "services"."expertise_id" = 79 
ORDER BY "external_score" DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Any ideas how to have this sql with the use of scopes?

Thanks!

Comment: can be linked to this issue: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5230

Comment: it seems multiple params scope are not working for me. here is how I called it https://pastebin.com/4QuS81jE